# Detecting end of programmatic UIScrollView scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm doing programmatic scrolling in UITableViews with scrollToRowAtIndexPath, which does not trigger scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. What is a good way to detect when this scrolling has completed?

I ask because in my code:

```
[tableView1 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
[tableView2 scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath2 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];

// Additional methods here
```

occasionally the later, additional methods fire before this scrolling has completed. I'd like to use something more fool-proof than performSelector: afterDelay:.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried [`scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:)? It may have the same issue as your other delegate method, but it's worth a shot. The docs specifically say it's called at the end of `setContentOffset:animated:` and `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`, which I have a hunch may be used to implement `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:`.

**Edit:** it's been confirmed that `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` gets called at the end of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:`. Thanks Ian!

Comment: Huh, I missed that method in the Docs. I can confirm it does get called at the end of scrollToRowAtIndexPath: (most of the time?! - UIScrollViews seem buggy to me) and is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: For me it gets called too often. I have a textField in a cell and if its focused this gets called immediately and then again after the animation... Bummer.